# Getting started with FTS3 or FTS4 on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, full-text-search

We have a couple tables in our database where we search using LIKE on iOS.  It is pretty slow the larger the data grows.  I got directed towards FTS3/FTS4, and read through some of the documentation.  I'm a bit unsure on how to get started.  (Please correct me if my statements are incorrect and I misinterpreted something in the documentation).  It sounds like a virtual table is just a table that is not stored on disk.  So if we have 4 columns that we currently search on using LIKE, do I create 4 virtual tables, inserting the entries from our original table into the rows of one of our new virtual tables, then on situations where I would normally search on that column, search in the new virtual table with the MATCH syntax, if that part is correct so far, I'm kind of stuck on what to do next.  Cause I'd need a lookup back into my original table to get the rest of the columns that are associated with that row.

Or do people create copies of their entire database into a virtual table and just get their information that way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual tables are not *directly* stored on disk, but they typically use several internal 'normal' tables to actually store the data, and just change how the data is accessed.
(see [Shadow Tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_9_1))

You can put several text columns into one FTS table, and [search either one or all of them](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3):

> Normally, a token or token prefix query is matched against the FTS table column specified as the left-hand side of the MATCH operator. Or, if the special column with the same name as the FTS table itself is specified, against all columns.

FTS tables [are not able to do 'normal' queries efficiently](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_4), so it's likely you still need your original table. The FTS table's `docid` column typically is the primary key of the original table.

If your original table also containts all the text, you can use an [external content FTS table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2) to save some space.